# mongoDb : How to get DB/connection reference from collection reference?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb connection making class which I cannot modify for some reason.
It gives me a reference to a target mongodb collection in which I can do operations .
eg.

```
  $myColl = mongoConnect::targetCollection($key);
  $myColl->insert( array("_id" => "SDFWERWER" ,"data" => 42 ));
// How can I get a reference to the DATABASE using $myColl, so that I can use some 
// command like :
  $myDb->command();  <--- some DB reference like this.
```

EDIT : i got it ,
  **$myColl->db   gives reference to db value in PHP driver :)**

Comment: Pretty weird question. The database is likely reachable from the "mongoConnect" object since it needs the database to return a collection by name. Which language is this? PHP, Perl? Please provide reasonable information what MongoConnect is! We must not guess what you are actually doing.

Comment: I have already mentioned mongoConnect is a class providing me a reference to a target mongodb collection, it makes a connection and selects a DB and then a collection based on certain criterias,and returns the collection. My requirement is to obtain a reference to Database from this collection reference

Comment: What driver are you using? I use MongoDB using the C# driver and I know how to do it in there - if I know what driver you are using I can point you in the right direction

Comment: @Ada .. thanks i got it in PHP driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [PHP driver documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php) for the Collection class

It shows there is a public field containing a reference to the DB ($db).

Hope this helps!